# Please check my proof on complex differentiation

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a region, $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be complex differentiable so that $\Im(f)=0$. Then f is constant.

$f=u+iv=u$

Since the function is complex differentiable the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold:

$u_x=v_y=0$

$u_y=-v_x=0$

Since both derivatives are zero, $u$ has to be constant.

Is this true? It seems almost too easy to me.

Comment: Does "region" imply connected?

Comment: In this case yes.

Comment: Yes, it *is* that easy.

Comment: @illuminatitruthseeker  Then you are good.  It is false without connectedness.